# SQLで同じ値を持つカラムの数も一緒に取得する方法を教えてください

Tags: mysql, sql

下記のようなusersテーブルから同じnameの人の数を一緒に取得するにはどのようなSQLを実行すればよいのでしょうか？データベースはMySQL5.6です。

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Yamada" |
| 2 | "Yamada" |
| 3 | "Suzuki" |
| 4 | "Honda" |

SQLの実行結果として、このようなものをイメージしています。

| id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Yamada" | 2 |
| 2 | "Yamada" | 2 |
| 3 | "Suzuki" | 1 |
| 4 | "Honda" | 1 |

Comment: この状態でさらに `"Yamada"`  が増減したら全データベースを再スキャンして該当レコードの `count` を増減させるんですか？　性能的に好ましくないような気のせいがします。

Comment: 何のためにこのようなことをする必要があるのかをもう一度考えてみたほうが良いと思います。正規化の観点からも別テーブルにして、各IDのカウント値を集計するカラムを作ったほうが良いと思います。

Comment: カラムを追加するのではなくデータを取得するときに毎回集約関数等を利用して計算したいということでいいですか？

Comment: はい、カラムを追加するのではなくデータを取得するときに毎回集約関数等を利用して計算したいです。質問の内容が悪かったので修正しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これは**編集前の内容にあわせた回答**です。
第三者にも役立つ内容と判断して、そのまま投稿します。

---

行の増減や値の更新、時間の変動など、外部的な要因に連動して変化するデータをテーブルに格納することは、コメントにあるように良い設計ではありません。

例えばご質問の`name`カラムや年齢を示す`age`カラムなどが上記の例に当たります。
「テーブル更新するたびにupdateすればいいじゃないか」「毎晩バッチ処理で年齢計算できるから問題ない」と思う方もいるかもしれませんが、今後の開発で増えたプログラムでupdateを忘れたり、バッチ処理がエラーで動かなくなったりした時に破綻します。

毎回`count`を集計するSQLをコピペする状況を解決するために、[`VIEW`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC_(%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9))が用意されています。
VIEWを定義することで、集計関数を使用したSQL実行結果をまるでテーブルのように扱えます。
VIEWの使用を検討してください。

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table user (
  id int,
  name varchar(30)
  );

create index idx_user_name on user(name);

insert into user values(1, 'Yamada');
insert into user values(2, 'Yamada');
insert into user values(3, 'Suzuki');
insert into user values(4, 'Honda');

# 下記のSQLのselect以下が「どのようなSQLを実行すればよいのでしょうか？」の回答に該当します
create view user_count as
select u.*, c.cnt
from   user u,
       (select name, count(1) cnt from user group by name) c
where  u.name = c.name;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from user_count;
```

| id | name | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yamada | 2 |
| 2 | Yamada | 2 |
| 3 | Suzuki | 1 |
| 4 | Honda | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ignFAi32tZXabbYcKZQfKD/0)